# Is it possible to know whether another app is in background or foreground?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm going to develop a task manager app.

But before starting, I want to know my app can detect other applications status or not? for example are they in running background or they are in foreground?

Does Android system provide some methods to determine this?

Comment: Everybody is answering that this is possible, but I think the methods that used to be good for determining which application is currently in foreground, is deprecated.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re: What are these deprecated methods?

Comment: i.e. getRecentTasks() is deprecated since api 21 L. But I hope anybody knows a workaround, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, AFAIK, at a time, only one application can be in foreground mode. That means, if you run your application (task manager), it will be in foreground mode and other application that were running will be in background mode until they are being killed. So you don't have to list out the foreground application list.

To get the running (current application is in foreground and others are background)application list, you can use the following codes:

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Nevertheless, to know which application is in foreground you can use the following codes after the above codes:

```
for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
    if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
        Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do determine which application really is in foreground?

Comment: My app should be able to do it's job even if it is running in background mode. So I have to know which app is in foreground and don't kill him.

Comment: I would be glad if this works. Is this reliable? I.e. if I open Whats app, it will directly have the importance IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND? So that I can write a service which fetches continuously the app importance?

Comment: Certainly it will work, if you have confusion do some study on this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html

Comment: @kikio Please report your result if you are going to test this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this utility and it has always done the job, needs API 14+ though
It's worth mentioning that using the ActivityManager, fails at some cases, like force stop and stuff like that, plus it does't offer the utility of having a callback once the application state has changed

[Here](https://gist.github.com/steveliles/11116937)

Comment: Where do you get the Application object from another third party application?

Comment: What do you mean ? just copy this file to your project and use your own application object

Comment: So, this class just inspects the lifecycle of my own application. I don't think that is what op asked for.

Comment: You're absolutely right, i have mis read the question, thought he wanted to his own application status, thanks for pointing that out Jack

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **ACTIVITY MANAGER** we can get all state of other app.